# Amazon s3 backup без хренения временного дампа базы

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon

Как делать бекап дазы данных сразу на Amazon s3 без хранения копии дампа на сервере?

У меня идея — использовать [драйвер s3 для маунта хранилища на сервер](http://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs) и делать бекап туда, но заказчик хочет ещё варианты.

Comment: с помощью чего вы «общаетесь» с хранилищем? если речь о программе aws, то в ней, насколько вижу, возможность использования stdin [реализована](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/903). если с помощью curl, так это [всегда можно было сделать](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/769).

Comment: Я хотел использовать Fuse driver

Comment: http://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs/# Наподобие этого

Answer (score 1):

согласно [документации](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) можно при отправке файлов использовать *stdin* в качестве источника:

```
$ aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/stream.txt
```

то есть, в приложении к вашему случаю:

```
$ программа-формирующая-поток-данных | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/stream.txt
```

---

ещё одна возможность: без использования всяких надстроек обращаться к серверу непосредственно по протоколу *https*. [вот здесь](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/769) приведён пример скрипта.